# "Auf gar keinen Fall" -- wieso Akkusativ?

Tags: dative, accusative, declension

Ich habe soeben bemerkt, dass es "auf gar keinen Fall" ist.

Doch wieso heißt es

- "gar keinen Fall"
- und nicht "gar keinem Fall"?

Es kann sein, dass es einfach so ist, aber ich möchte wissen, ob es irgendeine Regel gibt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die einfache Regel: Bis auf die räumliche Bedeutung nimmt "auf" immer Akkusativ. "Auf" hat dabei aber eine Vielzahl von Bedeutungen, die vom folgenden Nomen oder vom Verb bestimmt wird. Diese Bedeutungen sind teilweise von der räumlichen ableitbar, manchmal aber auch nicht. Siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/auf) für eine Liste. Während "Stunde auf Stunde" noch nach stapeln und sinnvoll klingt, habe ich keine Ahnung, wofür "auf" in "auf zwei Wochen verreisen" steht.

Es ist *auf* jeden Fall so, dass einige zeitliche Wörter wie "Fall", "Mal", "Schlag" mit "auf" und Akkusativ verwendet werden, ohne dass klar ist, wofür das "auf" hier steht. Interessanterweise kann man hier auch "im" verwenden, mit Dativ: "in keinem Fall", "in einem Mal", "in einem Schlag" statt "auf keinen Fall", "auf ein Mal", "auf einen Schlag". Aber sie sind etwas ungebräuchlicher.

Comment: Interessant ist, dass sowohl *auf* als auch *in* Wechselpräpostionen sind, aber bei "auf keinen Fall" / "in keinem Fal"* *auf* mit Akkusativ, *in* aber mit Datv verwendet wird.Ich glaube nicht, dass es großen Sinn hat, sich zu fragen, warum das so ist.

Comment: "auf zwei Wochen verreisen" —— Das habe ich noch nie gehört. Ist das eventuell regional/dialektal? Dialekte haben ihre jeweils eigenen grammatischen Regeln.

Comment: "ohne dass klar ist, wofür das 'auf' hier steht" —— Bei "auf jeden Fall", "auf ein Mal" und "auf einen Schlag" für die Art und Weise (modal).